# ID in an html tag inside a php script

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
  foreach ($myquery_domain->result() as $row ){
    $domain = $row->domain;
    $domain_id = $row->domain_id;
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>';
        echo '<span class="flip_domain" id="$domain_id">+</span>'.$domain;
      echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
?>
```

Hi, I want my $domain_id to be the ID of my . Could Someone help me pls. Thank you.

Comment: you know, it makes to sense to indent these echoes.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Agreed. +1 for awesome syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  foreach ($myquery_domain->result() as $row ){
    $domain = $row->domain;
    $domain_id = $row->domain_id;
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>';
        echo '<span class="flip_domain" id="'.$domain_id.'">+</span>'.$domain;
      echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to concatenate it with a `.` - same as `$domain`:

```
echo '<span class="flip_domain" id="'.$domain_id.'">+</span>'.$domain;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes for string literals means that PHP won't substitute variables for you. So, use double-quotes instead:

```
 echo "<span class='flip_domain' id='$domain_id'>+</span>".$domain;
```

Comment: Wrapping attribute values in single quotes is not valid xHTML - though I'm not sure how many people care about that anymore these days...

Comment: @JosephSilber oh, really? who said you that?

Comment: @JosephSilber you're right, but I certainly don't care. HTML5, baby.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - I just always thought that since xHTML has to be valid XML - and XML uses double quotes - single quotes would not be valid. However, now that you're challenging me, I searched around and it turns out that even XML allows for values to be wrapped in single quotes. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1):

I like the readable syntax:

```
<?php
  foreach ($myquery_domain->result() as $row ){
    $domain = $row->domain;
    $domain_id = $row->domain_id;
?>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="flip_domain" id="<?php echo $domain_id; ?>">+</span> <?php echo $domain; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>

<?php
  }
?>
```